# C parsing a string into an array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, c-strings

While defining an array of strings, I usually declare it similar to the following:

```
    char *arr[5] =
{
    "example0",
    "example1",
    "example2",
    "example3",
    "example4"
};
```

Where I'm having a problem is I don't know how to pass a variable into one of the elements of `arr`.

For instance,

```
char str[6] = "1.0.0.1";

char *arr[6] =
{
    "example0",
    "example1",
    "example2",
    "example3 %s", str,
    "example4"
};
```

Of course, this doesn't work, it's just a basic illustration of what I'm having trouble with.

I also know I can later use `strncat()` or even `snprintf()` but, to avoid the pain of handling memory with those, I just want to know if parsing a variable into one of the strings of the array is possible at declaration.

Comment: The posted code would "work" if `str` were sufficiently sized for the initialization value you're providing. By "work" I mean *compile*. Obviously It isn't going to magically plant `str` into the `example3 %s` string at the apparent format specifier location.

Comment: Ah, that magic is what I need. That code compiles anyways, by doesnt work I meant that magic doesnt happen. Also, 6 is enough for handling str as another element.

Comment: I believe in C++, you can do something like: `"bla bla text " + str + "bla bla text"`. Nothing like that in C?

Comment: This isn't C++, and no, you don't get that functionality in C. And read what I said *again*. I didn't say `arr` wasn't sufficiently sized. I said `str` is not. The initialization literal `"1.0.0.1"` you're providing requires 8 chars of storage; you're specifically declaring `str` as `char[6]`. 8 doesn't fit into 6, no matter how hard you push.

Comment: @WhozCraig Gotchu, read it wrong at that time. But still 8 isn't given as size? At compile run-time the sizeof str is added into `arr[3]`. So it's just like `snprintf()` except I need to that in the latter. EDIT: I mean if the thing I said was a thing, the size of str would be added to arr[3] because it's declaration. Since it wasn't declared yet, a size of 8 shouldn't be defined for `arr[3]` *If what I said existed*

Comment: The undersized array I have pointed out now *twice* is `str`, not `arr` If you removed literally *every* line from you program except `char str[6] = "1.0.0.1";` the problem I'm describing would remain. `str` is undersized. You cannot shove 8 chars into a char buffer declared to be 6. If there is a way I can say that differently than I already have, it eludes me. And the sizeof of `str` is *not* added to `arr[3]`. The array `arr` holds six char *pointers*, not char arrays. The *fifth* element in that array, `arr[4]`, is the base address of `str`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Just realized `"1.0.0.1"` exceeds. Counting chars be difficult with dots :(. Sorry for your time spent on explaining this simple thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... if parsing a variable into one of the strings of the array is possible at declaration.

At compile time, could concatenate as below:

```
#define STR "1.0.0.1"
char str[] = STR;

char *arr[6] = { 
    "example0",
    "example1",
    "example2",
    "example3" " " STR, // Forms "example3 1.0.0.1"
    "example4"
};
```

---

Perhaps OP is interested in something formed during run-time. It uses a [variable length array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99).

```
void foobar(const char *str) {
  int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "example3 %s", str);
  char a[n]; // VLA.
  snprintf(a, sizeof a, "example3 %s", str);

  char *arr[6] = {
      "example0",
      "example1",
      "example2",
      a,
      "example4"
  };

  printf("<%s>\n", arr[3]);
}

int main(void) {
  foobar("1.0.0.1");
}
```

Output

```
<example3 1.0.0.>
```

Alternatively the space for the *string* could have been done via an allocation.

```
char *a = malloc(n + 1u);
sprintf(a, "example3 %s", str);
....
free(a);
```

Comment: I really don't understand why you used `char str[]` in your example. That is a string constant not a variable.

Comment: @ÖmerGök A variable would not work at compile time.  You would need something like `sprintf("example3 %s", str);` which only works at runtime.

Comment: ^^^ including the target buffer, obviously.

Comment: @ÖmerGök `char str[] = STR;` is illustrative code to show how `str` and `arr` can both derive their initializations from `STR`.  `str` is not needed to initialize `arr`.

Comment: `snprintf(arr[3], MAX, "example3 %s", str)` wouldn't work anyways. At this point, I think I should just allocate sufficient memory before doing anything.

Comment: @ÖmerGök The posted goal is "... possible at declaration".  `snprintf()` happens later.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I understand. Still, I said passing a 'variable', not a literal string. So, i think this answer is incorrect, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @ÖmerGök This answer is direct modification to your question code. If it's not what you want, please edit the question with code that matches your problem. Probably a complete function, if not a complete [mcve].

Comment: Secondary note: the syntax for having the compiler figure out the length of `str` is good design, and one should use it where possible.

Comment: @hyde The point I was trying to make in the question is that `snprintf()` is already doable after the declaration. There is no need for passing a literal string as is the same with just typing it.

Comment: @ÖmerGök So, please clarify question by editing it. There may be solutions, but it depends on details, if it works for you or not. In any case, if compile time string literal concatenation doesn't do what you want, you need to call a function.